# Is this an ARM Compiler code generation error?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, embedded, ds-5

I am working on an embedded system which includes an ARM Cortex-M4 CPU and a few peripherals. One of the peripherals contains blocks of SRAM which are accessible from the CPU side (via the AHB bus), but access must be a word size transaction (using LDR). If a byte transaction is performed (LDRB), an exception is generated.

In my code, I am reading a value from an array in that memory and assigning it to a local variable. The declarations are like this:

```
typedef enum
{
     eType0 = 0,
     eType1 = 1,
} type_t;

type_t    arr_type;
uint32_t *array  = BUF_ADDR; // array on periph. memory
uint32_t  offset = 0;

arr_type = (type_t) array[offset]; // exception!
```

When running this code, I get an exception when reading the memory. It happens that this assignment generates the assembly code:

```
LDRB R1, [R2, R3, LSL #2]; // R2=array, R3=offset
```

This is also true even when I add parentheses and explicitly cast the expression:

```
type = (uint32_t) (array[offset]);
```

The way to resolve this was to declare `arr_type` as `uint32_t` instead of `type_t`. Now, the code is:

```
LDR R1, [R2, R3, LSL #2];
```

Is this an expected behaviour? I'd assume that the parentheses and the cast (if not the natural type of the `array` pointer) would make the compiler generate and `LDR` instruction. Hence this looks like a bug.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug, the compiler is generally allowed to use a smaller access (which is also automatically aligned as per the usual rules).

Comment: The compiler _knows_ it's only going to use 1 byte, so why should it waste time and space doing a word load plus an extra instruction to mask it down when it also knows that a byte load does that for free?

Comment: Did you try declaring array as `uint32_t volatile*`? Volatile more or less means "don't mess with my memory accesses"

Comment: @rici - as I commented in @Ross Ridge's answer, this actually works. But I am not sure your interpretation of `volatile` (as put here) is correct.

Comment: I just love people who downvote a question or an answer w/o expression why they think it is inappropriate....

Comment: @ysap I didn't downvote but for your information, [explaining downvotes is discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777/547981) here on SO.

Comment: My explanation is obviously informal but not inexact. Volatile indicates that the compiler must perform memory reads and writes as indicated by the code and in order. It cannot skip reading half of an int, for example, because volatile reads are considered side effects.

Comment: Sorry, the down vote was mine. I seem to have accidentally clicked it somehow.

Comment: Slap your hardware designers for designing an apb peripheral that issues a bus fault on a byte access.

Comment: Slap your system programmer for not understanding hardware.  Thank the hardware designers for not using extra gates and power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler can normally use whatever load instructions it wants so long as it works, from perspective of the program itself, as if the 32-bit load implied by `array[offset]` was performed. Since the value loaded ends up being truncated to 8 bits when stored in `arr_type`, it doesn't change the value stored in `arr_type` if the compiler uses an 8-bit load instead.

To tell the compiler that size of the memory access is important and has visible effects outside of the program itself, you should use the `volatile` qualifier.

```
type_t    arr_type;
uint32_t volatile *array = BUF_ADDR;
uint32_t  offset = 0;

arr_type = (type_t) array[offset];
```

More generally you should use the `volatile` qualifier when performing any sort of memory mapped I/O. It not only ensures that accesses are always performed using the intended size (where possible), it also guarantees that that accesses aren't removed or reordered.

Comment: Thanks. You are probably right that as far as it is the C standard's concern, the actual implementation of the memory access does not matter. Surprisingly, `volatile`ing the array pointer generated the expected code. However, I am not sure why. Is it b/c this way the compiler make the reading of the whole word atomic? If so, what if the type was >32bit?

Comment: It doesn't make it atomic, but it does force accessing the whole size.

Comment: @ysap With `volatile` you're more or less dependent on the compiler doing the right thing. The standard doesn't guarantee that the access is atomic, only that can't be removed or moved. So you have to assume that the compiler will use 32-bit load or store store instruction when accessing a 32-bit volatile object, but a conforming compiler could still use multiple 8-bit load/stores. There's just no reason for it to do so. But in the case of a 64-bit volatile object, if there isn't a 64-bit atomic load/store instruction, the compiler has no other option.

Comment: @RossRidge - yes, that is my point - volatility tells the compiler that a variable or a location can be modified asynchronously with the current thread running, which is why the compiler should not make assumptions on the memory's content when it comes to optimize the code (an obvious example - don't take an operation involving a volatile outside of a loop). In the case in question, I see no problem in loading a byte and storing it in the byte variable, even if the whole word containing that byte is a volatile (which is really not, in *our* specific case).

Comment: This is no different than the 64-bit case, where there is no way for the compiler to create this atomicity for the load instruction, even if the 64-bit pointer type is volatile. If this was a problem, then any implementation was non-conforming, I guess.

Comment: @ysap I'm sorry I don't see what point you're trying to make. The C standard doesn't provide any means to guarantee that a memory access uses the 32-bit ARM LDR instruction, but it also doesn't provide any means to access a block of SRAM on some device via the AHB bus. You're dependent on the compiler doing right thing when you assign `BUF_ADDR` to `array` and then again doing the right thing when you dereference that pointer. Both actions invoke undefined behaviour according to the standard. Similarly you're dependent on the compiler doing the right thing with `volatile`.

Comment: @ysap Also you're looking at `volatile` the wrong way. It doesn't tell the compiler that the object can be modified asynchronously. It's not about threads, the keyword pretty much predates them. It tells the compiler that the accesses to the volatile object can't be reordered, removed or incomplete. For example you can use it to force apparently redundant or unnecessary reads of a device register whose value is meaningless and never changes, but the act of reading it causes the device to do something.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile with the flag --enum_is_int your access to the enum will be 32 bits and aligned.

Comment: Thanks. This is correct, but we have dozens of enums throughout the codebase that should be minimally sized.